# Can I disable the shell theme for my dock?

Tags: themes, unity-dash, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I customized my dock (dash to dock) a little bit with the dconf application and I really liked it, but when I activated my shell theme (dracula) it kind of ruined the neat look and I can't fix it in dconf. I added two pictures with the shell theme activated and deactivated. I use Ubuntu LTS 22.04. Can I exclude dash to dock from using the shell theme somehow?

EDIT: Here is the scss from the dock:

```css
  /* DASHBOARD */

  #dash {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: $topbar_color;
    background-color: $topbar_bg_color;
    padding: 6px 0;
    border: 1px solid $borders_color;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;

    &:rtl {
      border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
    }

    .placeholder {
      background-image: url("assets/dash-placeholder.svg");
      background-size: contain;
      height: 24px;
    }

    .empty-dash-drop-target {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
    }

  }

  .dash-item-container > StWidget {
    padding: 4px 8px;
  }

  .dash-label { //osd tooltip
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    color: $topbar_color;
    background-color: $topbar_bg_color;
    text-align: center;
    -x-offset: 8px;
  }
```

EDIT 2: I found some more scss:

```css
/* DASHBOARD */
#dash {
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  background-color: rgba(40, 42, 54, 0.95);
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid #1b1c24;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px; }
  #dash:rtl {
    border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px; }
  #dash .placeholder {
    background-image: url("assets/dash-placeholder.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    height: 24px; }
  #dash .empty-dash-drop-target {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px; }

.dash-item-container > StWidget {
  padding: 4px 8px; }

.dash-label {
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  background-color: rgba(40, 42, 54, 0.95);
  text-align: center;
  -x-offset: 8px; }
```

[image: Without the new theme]

[image: With the new theme]

Comment: Could you try digging into the files of your custom theme itself, and maybe comment out sections that are aimed at the dock? (Before altering anything however, create a backup copy of the original state of the files.)

Comment: Is that code snippet from the "Dracula" shell theme that is currently active? Here is how to comment code in CSS / SCSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments After commenting some stuff out, you need to restart the gnome-shell for the changes to take effect. On Ubuntu 20.04 it is done by pressing Alt+F2, which reveals the "run command" dialogue, putting an `r` into the field, and pressing Enter. That restarts the gnome-shell, and you get to see the updated look of the dock. Afterwards you get to play around with the code to find out what to comment out and what to leave.

Comment: I commented out all the css stuff relating to the dock and some of it worked so thank you very much